# Is this the correct way to solve for center of gravity $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $R$ be the region below the graph of $y = x^2$ and above the $x$-axis and between $x = -2$ and $x = 2$. Find the center of gravity $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ of $R$.

Work:

$A = \frac{16}{3}$

$\bar{x} = \frac{3}{16} \int x^3 dx$
= 0

$\bar{y} = \frac{3}{32} \int x^4 dx$
$= \frac{6}{5}$

$(\bar{x}, \bar{y}) = (0,\frac{6}{5})$

Is this correct?

Thank you

Comment: What is the significance of $A$?  Add descriptions in between equations to explain what you're doing.  Also - a trick: since your region is symmetric about the $y$-axis, you immediately know that $\bar{x}=0$ without any math.

Comment: Yes! It is correct

Comment: $A$ is of course the area of the region. Agreeing with @WillCunningham, $\bar{y}$ is correctly written (modulo limits of integration).

Comment: Thanks all! is the final answer correct?

Comment: @WillCunningham how do I know that x-bar is 0? I am not good at math. I don't see how that works. Could you please explain more.